# Degree of freedom of different distributions: Chi-Square Goodness of Fit Test

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, degrees-of-freedom

I try to understand why the number of constraints differ for the distributions in the table below, for the Chi-square goodness of fit test. I found the content in the following link.

https://www.statisticssolutions.com/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test/

"Degree of freedom: In Chi-Square goodness of fit test, the degree of freedom depends on the distribution of the sample. The following table shows the distribution and an associated degree of freedom:"

[image]

Comment: I would warmly recommend using a different statistical resource.  The first hint of problems is its inability to spell "binomial;" the second is the absence of any real explanation of the information in this table; the third is the erroneous formula for the test statistic; and we could go on from there.  That's hilarious in light of the site's Orwelllian motto "Advancement Through Clarity."

Comment: I'd add to whuber's recommendation; I'm yet to follow a link to that site from a question here where I saw anything I'd recommend reading.